multiple if and else within kql azure
Trying to write a kql query where date should be populated in the "date" column based on the if condition :-
If RawData has a string starting with "" then the result of this - substring(RawData, 0, 1900) which is a date should be populated in the column Date.
If RawData has a string starting with "DD" or "II" then result of this- substring(RawData, 22, 1900)  which is a date should be populated in the column Date.
And similarly there are 2-3 more conditions. How to implement this? I was trying something like this -
 T
| project Date=substring(RawData, 0, 24), RawData
 | project Date, RawData=substring(RawData, 0, 1900)
| project Date = iff(RawData contains_cs  "||", "substring(RawData, 22, 

1900)","substring(RawData, 0, 1900)"), RawData

Can you provide your sample input data and expected output data based on your condition for better understanding?

As far as I have understood your question, you could do the following:
let T = datatable (
    RawData: string
)
[
     "DD 2024-07-31 23:25:01.434 Callingfunctionality . II 2024-07-31 23:25:01.412 calling refer-functionality performance tune"
]; 
T
| extend SplitDD = split(split(RawData, "DD ")[1], " ")
| extend SplitII = split(split(RawData, "II ")[1], " ")
| extend DateDD = todatetime(strcat(SplitDD[0], " ", SplitDD[1]))
| extend DateII = todatetime(strcat(SplitII[0], " ", SplitII[1]))
| project DateDD, DateII

So using extend essentially and split.
Here is a working Sample.
UPDATE 2 (with union):
let T = datatable (
    RawData: string
)
[
     "DD 2024-07-31 23:25:01.434 Callingfunctionality . II 2024-07-31 23:25:01.412 calling refer-functionality performance tune"
]; 
let DD = 
T
| extend Split = split(split(RawData, "DD ")[1], " ")
| extend Date = todatetime(strcat(Split[0], " ", Split[1]))
| project Date;
let II = 
T
| extend Split = split(split(RawData, "II ")[1], " ")
| extend Date = todatetime(strcat(Split[0], " ", Split[1]))
| project Date;
union DD, II

Here is this working sample.
Result:


cre_gw_customlogs_a_CL
| extend Date = iff(RawData contains_cs "DD", substring(RawData, 3, 25), " "), RawData
| extend Date = iff(RawData contains_cs "II", substring(RawData, 3, 23), " "), RawData
| extend Date = substring(RawData, 0, 19), RawData
| extend Date = todatetime(Date)
| project Date, RawData  in this query the DD condition and the II condition is not working. the third condition extend Date=substring(RawData, 0, 19), RawData

DD 2024-07-31 23:25:01.434 Callingfunctionality .
II 2024-07-31 23:25:01.412 calling refer-functionality performance tune

the sample data looks like above..

Ah, I understand it now. I will improve my query in my answer. Give me a second.

I have edited my answer and used your sample data. Please have a look. We can later add your other open cases.

I want everything in one same Date column.

The requirement is to only capture the timestamp

See my UPDATE in my answer. Now you should have a sample code for everything.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
